# Проблема с натяжкой сайта на WordPress

Tags: wordpress

не могу натянуть свой сайт на WordPress , загрузил чистую тему через сайт `underscores`.

после загрузки на темы нажимаю на `Активировать` и WP падает , в логах пишет

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare wp_widgets_init() (previously declared in /var/www/bubiyk__olex/data/www/babiyk-portfolio.co.ua/wp-includes/widgets.php:1805) in /var/www/bubiyk__olex/data/www/babiyk-portfolio.co.ua/wp-content/themes/hr_themes/functions.php on line 122
```

Comment: Судя по тексту ошибки, wp_widgets_init() уже есть в файле /wp-includes/widgets.php, а Вы пытаетесь повторно объявить эту функцию в functions.php своей темы. Вот здесь есть решение аналогичной проблемы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44106541/error-500-php-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-thim-widgets-inits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По той инфе, что вы предоставили трудно понять в чем ошибка. Вот несколько практических советов:

1. Проверьте еще раз что у вас последняя версия WP и что все файлы корректно разархивированы и закачались на сервер.
2. Убедитесь (если нужно, пройдите еще раз процедуру установки) что WP корректно установлен, то есть что установка прошла без ошибок.
3. Проверьте пути загрузки темы. Тема должна быть загружена в разархивированном формате (!) в папку wp-content/themes/ . То есть, если у вас тема называется, к примеру, "bubik", то в папке /wp-content/themes/bubik/ должны быть папки /inc/, /js/ и т.д. - из скачанной темы underscores.
4. Возможно у вас уже установлены какие-то плагины, отключите их перед активацией темы. Очень похоже что один из них конфликтует с темой. Включайте плагины потом по одному чтобы понять какой именно является причиной ошибки.

Comment: проблема решилась - заменою названий функций в `function.php` на другие названия